# Basic cmd number loop

Tags: loops, cmd, numbers

I have created a simple program to print numbers 1 to 10 and store them in a text file:

```
@echo off
SET /A X=1

:START
IF %X% LEQ 10 (
               ECHO %X%>>C:\TXT.TXT
               SET /A X+=1
               GOTO START
              )

PAUSE
```

Output that I am getting is:

```
ECHO OFF
10
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a for loop for this (not an if statement):

```
FOR /L %i IN (1,1,10) do echo %i
```

(this loops from 1 to 10 in command line)

See also: http://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html

EDIT (as I tried to put the code in my comment -> if you change your code to output in the console, you'll see that your code does work, but in your case the txt only has the last time your echo'd):

```
@echo off
SET /A X=1

:START
IF %X% LEQ 10 (
               ECHO %X%
               SET /A X+=1
               GOTO START
              )
pause
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternavtive and much better script update.
But If i had to use the script i submitted above,
what's the mistake and why isn't it working the way intended it to?

Comment: Alright I think I got it,
if i type 

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

then I get my desired output. **Is it because I need to have the script read the whole block before executing the program?**

The reason I tried the "IF" command is that I am just starting out with batch programming and I wanted to learn more about "IF" command before I go further in to advance commands like "FOR".

The link which you added along with your answer was really informative, thanks for that :)

Comment: a loop function should normally be used for this logic. However, your IF statement does actually work. However, the reason why you see in txt.txt only the 10, is because that is the last thing you wrote to the file. Try just to output it to the console:

@echo off
SET /A X=1

:START
IF %X% LEQ 10 (
               ECHO %X%
               SET /A X+=1
               GOTO START
              )
pause